# Where is $xy/(|x|+|y|)$ differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

> Where is the function $f:E^2\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|} &  , \ \text{if} \ (x,y)\ne(0,0)\\ 
> 0 &  , \ \text{if} \ (x,y)=(0,0). \end{cases}$$ differentiable?

We have $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \begin{cases} \frac{y(|x|+|y|)\pm xy|y|}{(|x|+|y|)^2}, &  x>0\\ 
 \frac{y(|x|+|y|)\pm xy|y|}{(|x|+|y|)^2}, & x<0. \end{cases}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \begin{cases} \frac{x(|x|+|y|)\pm xy|x|}{(|x|+|y|)^2}, &  y>0\\ 
 \frac{x(|x|+|y|)\pm xy|x|}{(|x|+|y|)^2}, & y<0. \end{cases}$$

For $(x,y)\ne (0,0),$ the continuity of the partials $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ implies that $f$ is indeed differentiable at any $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$.

But what about for $(x,y)=(0,0)$?

Comment: If differentiability is at issue, then should you be helping yourself to $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$? I would think you would proceed by showing that the requisite limits exist everywhere except where they don't. (I suspect they exist everywhere except the origin.)

Answer (score 1):

First, note that this is at least continuous. (This is always a good first step, since if it isn't then we are done.) We have that $\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|} \leq \frac{\max(x^2,y^2)}{\max(|x|,|y|)} \leq \max(|x|,|y|) \rightarrow 0$ as $x,y \rightarrow 0$. So, it is continuous.

Now, suppose it is differentiable. Then $\lim \frac{f(h) - f(0) - Df(0) \cdot h}{h}$. Now, consider $h \equiv (h, 0)$. Then $\lim \frac{f(h) - f(0) - Df(0) \cdot h}{h} = \lim -D_{1}f(0) = 0$. Hence, this implies $D_{1}f(0) = 0$. Similarly, $D_{2}f(0) = 0$. Now we consider the direction $h \equiv (h, h)$. Then $f(h,h) = |h|/2$. But this is a contradiction, since then $\lim \frac{f(h) - f(0) - Df(0) \cdot h}{|(h,h)|} = \lim \frac{|h|/2}{\sqrt{2}\cdot|h|} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \neq 0$. Hence, it is not differentiable at zero.

Everywhere else, it is obvious that differentiability holds, since $f$ is a composition, product and/or quotient of differentiable functions.

Comment: Thank you Chris! For notational purposes, what is $D,D_1,D_2$?

Comment: Sorry, this is how I learned it and I find the notation clearner than the 'Leibnizian' way. $Df = [D_{1}f\; D_{2}f] = [\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\; \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}]$

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks a lot for the help! This question stumped me for $(0,0)$.

Comment: How to prove the function $\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|} $ is continuous on the $\mathbb{R}^2$ \  {(0,0)} ?